# More elegant way to handle progress update notifications

Tags: javascript

Hi i'm currently tracking the uploading of a file (as it compresses) and sending the progress back to the user through the GUI. My code is somewhat ugly-looking. Wondering if you guys might have a better way?

The booleans below are meant to prevent constant updates as i only want to update at certain 'checkpoints'. (in this case below, 25%, 50% and 75%).

```
let past25 = false;
let past50 = false;
let past75 = false;

ffmpeg(file.path)
.addOption('-hls_time', 10)
.addOption('-hls_list_size', 0)
.addOption('-f', 'hls')
.on('progress', (progress) => {
    let sendUpdate = false;

    if (progress.percent > 25 && past25 == false) {
        sendUpdate = past25 = true;
    } else if (progress.percent > 50 && past50 == false) {
        sendUpdate = past25 = past50 = true;
    } else if (progress.percent > 75 && past75 == false) {
        sendUpdate = past25 = past50 = past75 = true;
    }

    if (sendUpdate) {
        notifyUser(progress)
    }
})
```

Comment: Seems good enough to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps set an initial threshold and an increment and then use a single check. Also allows you to change the granularity of your updates by just changing the values.

```
let threshold = 25;
let increment = 25;

ffmpeg(file.path)
  .addOption('-hls_time', 10)
  .addOption('-hls_list_size', 0)
  .addOption('-f', 'hls')
  .on('progress', (progress) => {

    if (progress.percent > threshold) {
      notifyUser(progress);
      // account for skipping multiple 'checkpoints' by rounding to the next highest threshold
      threshold += Math.ceil((progress.percent - threshold) / increment) * increment;
    }

  });
```

Comment: I like this threshold idea - it's a great idea. But i need to make the maximum 100 %?

Comment: You don't need to worry about setting a max because `progress.percent` sets an upper limit for you. With the settings as they are you'll get notifications at 26,51,and 76, but if you set the initial threshold to 24 then it will trigger at 25,50,75 and 100.